# How to hide windows Terminal opened in Qt app?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, mingw-w64

First of all, there are similar questions but I think it's a different question because the Windows terminal appears only when I call `system()` and not when the app is launching in general.

I have a program with a gui written in C++ with Qt and built in qmake with a `.pro` file, using MinGW compiler. OS is Windows 10 in a virtual box.

I wrote the code in Ubuntu where it works as intended (no OS terminal visible at all), but now I am testing it in Windows. My Problem is that whenever I call `system()` or similar in my code to execute another program (supposedly in the background), Windows opens a cmd terminal in front of my gui. I have lots of these calls in my program and therefore there are lots of these windows popping up and disappearing while it runs.

I set main() to WinMain() and removed console from the qmake config, but that did not show any effect.

My `.pro` file (removed comments):

```
QT       += core gui

CONFIG -= console
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = regionfind-gui
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        regionfind.cpp \
        sagacmd.cpp

HEADERS += \
        regionfind.h \
        sagacmd.h \
        processingsteps.h
FORMS += \
        regionfind.ui

RESOURCES += \
        images.qrc
```

Build command (generated from QtCreator):

`C:\Qt\Qt5.12.3\5.12.3\mingw73_64\bin\qmake.exe C:\Users\dev\Documents\regionfind-gui\regionfind-gui.pro -spec win32-g++ && C:/Qt/Qt5.12.3/Tools/mingw730_64/bin/mingw32-make.exe qmake_all`

How do I get rid of these terminal windows? They do not open when the command does not have any output, but I can't suppress the general output or similar because in some cases I'm storing the output and printing it into my gui, using the following code:

```cpp
array<char, 128> buffer;
string result = getDescription(getStep()) + command + "\n";
unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose) > pipe(popen(command.c_str(), "r"), pclose);
if(!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed");
while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)  {
 result += checkOutput(buffer.data());
 getGui()->txtOutput->append(QString::fromStdString(removeNewlineAtEnd(buffer.data())));
 getGui()->txtOutput->repaint();
 cout << buffer.data() << flush;;
}
```

Examples: `system("mkdir C:\\Users\dev\\Documents\\testfolder")` does not open a window (no output) but `system("driverquery")` does.

Comment: Sorry for reposting. I deleted my first attempt because I thought the error was elsewhere, but it wasn't, so now posted again.

Comment: Does it open one terminal for all commands that is kept open or one terminal per command?

Comment: @nwp each call opens a new terminal and they close once the command terminates

Comment: It probably makes sense to transition to `QProcess` so you know of what happens to the processes you spawn instead of having to guess if they were successful. It also bypasses the console problem.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using the `QProcess` class:

```cpp
    QObject *parent;
    ...
    QString program = "driverquery";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
    myProcess->start(program);
    if (myProcess->waitForStarted(-1)) {
        while(myProcess->waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
            getGui()->txtOutput->append( myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() );
       }
    }
    // else report error or whatever
```

In the case of using a command application, you can do the following:

```cpp
    QObject *parent;
    ...
    QString program = "driverquery";

    QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
    QString command = QString("cmd.exe %1 \"%2 \"").arg(" /C ").arg(program);
    myProcess->start(command);
    if (myProcess->waitForStarted(-1)) {
        while(myProcess->waitForReadyRead(-1)) {
            getGui()->txtOutput->append( myProcess->readAllStandardOutput() );
       }
    }
    // else report error or whatever
```

Comment: I'm fiddling around with it, currently it crashes at `start(program)`, probably because I don't get the hang of the parent object yet. I will try further and let you know. Static execution with `QProcess::execute(...)` works but lacks the return of the output.

Comment: Where i put `QObject *parent;` is to remark to use your parent object, maybe the QMainWindow. So you must initialize the `new QProcess(<yourQObject*>)`

Comment: driverquery.exe is a console application. By default running this via `CreateProcessW` with standard I/O redirected to pipes will still allocate a console and create a window, unless steps are taken to suppress the console window (i.e. the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` creation flag) or to hide it using the process `STARTUPINFO`. Does `QProcess` suppress or hide the console window by default when standard I/O is redirected?

Comment: I edited to show you how to do with a console cmd.exe

Comment: @Gasteizko it works, but it still opens command windows. Now they are empty instead of showing the output, but they are still there.

Comment: I tested and I did not have that behaviour.